# Slick trouble sorting by nested query parameter

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-3.0

I was trying to apply the following SQL request to Slick but then blocked on the implementation (the following code is a transposed use case from the original problem).

```
select t1.worker_id,
time_tracked_by_worker_sum,
sum(time_tracked) as time_tracked_sum,
t1.area_id
from tracker as t1
left join
    (
    select worker_id as wid,
    sum(time_tracked) as time_tracked_by_worker_sum,
    from tracker
    where date = '2017-03-20'
    group by worker_id
    ) as t2 on (t1.worker_id = t2.wid)
where date = '2017-03-20'
group by worker_id, area_id
order by time_tracked_by_worker_sum desc, time_tracked_sum desc
limit 100
```

Then I draft this version :

```
val q1 = for {
  details <- trackerRecords.filter(_.date = '2017-03-20').groupBy(_.workerId).map(r => (r._1, r._2.map(_.timeTracked).sum))
  query <- trackerRecords.filter(_.date = '2017-03-20') if (query.workerId === details._1)
} yield (query, details)

val q2 = q1.sortBy(s => s._2._2) // time_tracked_sum sort is missing
val q3 = q2.groupBy(x => (x._1.workerId, x._1.areaId))
val q4 = q3.map{
  case (key, record) =>
    (record.map(_._1.worker_id),
    key._1,
    // time_tracked_sum sort is missing
    record.map(_._1.timeTracked).sum,
    record.map(_._1.areaId))
}
```

One of my problem is that I couldn't add a sort from the nested query, on my current implementation I couldn't apply both time_tracked_by_worker_sum and time_tracked_sum.

An other problem I have is to map my fields, due to my groupBy I get a ***No matching Shape found*** error.

FYI, here is the trackerRecords table query.

```
/**
 * TrackerRecord
 */
trait TrackerRecordTable  {

  this: Profile =>
  import profile.api._
  import jodaSupport._

  class TrackerRecords(tag: Tag) extends Table[TrackerRecord](tag, "tracker") {
    def workerId            = column[WorkerId]("worker_id", O.SqlType("INT"))
    def areaId              = column[AreaId]("area_id", O.SqlType("INT"))
    def timeTracked         = column[Hour]("time_tracked", O.SqlType("INT"))
    def date                = column[LocalDate]("date", O.SqlType("DATE"))
  }

  def trackerRecords = TableQuery[TrackerRecords]
}
```

Thanks for your help !